# Can I be certain that using pthread_kill to send a realtime signal will always suceed?

Tags: c, signals, posix

The context ...

See the posix signals and the two delivery mechanisms: a kind of *flag* mechanism, then dealing with the original or standard signals, and a queue mechanism, when dealing with the *extended*, aka realtime signals.

So I know (or presume) that a call to *pthread_kill* while passing, as arguments, a standard signal and a valid thread, will always suceed.

In contrast, we have that a call to *sigqueue* while passing, as arguments, a valid and reachable process id, as well as valids signal and value, will fail and return the *EAGAIN* error, when the signal queue is full.

Ignore that while the former function points to a thread, the latter points to a process: the focus here is in the *guarantee of delivery*.

The doubt ...

What I wonder is: what can I expect when using *pthread_kill* to send realtime signals? Because once the interface does not specify *EAGAIN* as a possible error, then if blindly based on the interface specification (as I can see in the man pages), I can presume that the call will always suceed.

Is this right? Or there is some kind of catch I'm not seeing?

I could not find, in the docs or questions I saw until now, a clear answer to that.

**EDIT**: to clarify about the possible meanings pointed out by John Bollinger through his answer, follows.

I assumed "realtime" as a short term referring to "signal numbers between `SIGRTMIN` ... `SIGRTMAX`". Dont't known if this assumption is right. And (wrongly it seems) that this range determined the delivery mechanism .. queue of something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I wonder is: what can I expect when using pthread_kill to send
> realtime signals?

It's unclear whether you can do that at all, depending in part on what you mean by "send realtime signals".  In particular, although [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_02) does attribute special delivery-order semantics to signal numbers between `SIGRTMIN` and `SIGRTMAX`, inclusive, it seems *not* to say that signals in that range are automatically queued.  Nor that signals outside that range are never queued.  On the contrary, it associates signal queuing with the manner in which signals are raised:

> Some signal-generating functions, such as high-resolution timer expiration, asynchronous I/O completion, interprocess message arrival, and the `sigqueue()` function, support the specification of an application-defined value [...]
> When a signal is generated by the `sigqueue()` function or any signal-generating function that supports the specification of an application-defined value, the signal shall be marked pending and, if the SA_SIGINFO flag is set for that signal, the signal shall be queued to the process along with the application-specified signal value. [...] It is unspecified whether signals so generated are queued when the SA_SIGINFO flag is not set for that signal.

So if by "send realtime signals" you mean "cause a signal to be queued for delivery" then I don't think `pthread_kill()` has that feature.  At minimum, POSIX does not specify that it does.  On the other hand, if you mean "send a signal in the range `SIGRTMIN` ... `SIGRTMAX`" then POSIX does not say that the signal will necessarily be queued, instead of delivered like any another signal, or even that `pthread_kill()` will send it at all (as far as the spec is concerned, it could fail with `EINVAL` instead).

> Because once the interface does not specify EAGAIN
> as a possible error, then if blindly based on the interface
> specification (as I can see in the man pages), I can presume that the
> call will always suceed.
>
> Is this right? Or there is some kind of catch I'm not seeing?

No, that does not seem to be right.  POSIX does not require `pthread_kill()` to send signals in the range `SIGRTMIN` ... `SIGRTMAX`.  It can fail with `EINVAL` instead.  And if it does send them, then POSIX does not require it to *queue* them.

Comment: It's worse than I thought. As it seems the implementation is completally free to decide what to do in this situation, aaaand ... forget something like strong *guarantee of delivery*, portable whatever, in uncharted territorys like this.

And I wondering if were safe to use signals in this range to unblock system calls in specific threads ... :-( ...by the way, couldn't up the answer.. new user, not enough privileges.

Comment: @EdsonFreitas Can on Linux. What other systems do you need? MacOS, FreeBSD, Illumos...? There aren't that many UNIXes in use out there.

Comment: @EdsonFreitas, even though you cannot up this answer, if you are satisfied with it then, as author of the question, you have the option to "accept" it by clicking the checkmark below the score.  That will award me some rep, and it should award you a couple of points too.

Comment: @PetrSkocik Currently, I use Linux, FreeBSD and MacOS, although the last one, lately more as a desktop environment. But yet ... there lies the iPhone development platform, as a little remainder that no one really knows the tomorrow :-). So this uncertainty is in part the reason I decided to take a look in possibilities more prone to work the same way in an extended mix of platforms, say hello to highly accepted standards. But of course, only until a certain limit.